# mongoDB - manual offline replication by one command

Tags: mongodb, replication, offline

I would like to have 2 databases: production and offline. My system will work with the production one. But time to time I would like to copy changes from production db to offline db.

In CouchDB you can use something like:

```
POST /_replicate HTTP/1.1
{"source":"example-database","target":"http://example.org/example-database"}
```

Is there other way than:

- mongodump/mongorestore
- db.cloneDatabase( "db0.example.net" )

...in mongoDB? I understand those operations as copying full content of database. Is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you have a few options here depending on the constraints your database system has. In addition to the options above, you could also:

- Set your offline database up as a secondary as part of a replica set. This replica could then be used for your offline work and would keep in sync with the primary. The added benefit to this is you will always have an additional copy of your data in case you run into issues with the primary. You may want to mark the "offline" replica as hidden so that it could never take over as primary. See the following links for more information: [Replication in MongoDB](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/replication/), [Replication Internals](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/replication-internals/)
- If you really just want point in time snap shots then another option would be to backup your database files and restore them to your offline cluster. The methods to do this vary according to your database setup and environment. The following is a good start for learning about backups: [MongoDB Backups](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Backups)